# Do AVG() with association table return 0 when no data in associated table

Tags: mysql, associations, average

Good day, I have the following tables:

- User ( id, ... )
- Object ( id, ... )
- Rate ( idObject, idUser, rate )

Where Rate associates one object to any number of users.

I would like to make a query that gets all Object rows, giving its rate AVG, so I started something like this:

```
SELECT
    `Object`.`*`,
    AVG( `Rate`.rate ) AS rate
FROM
    `Object`,
    `Rate`
WHERE
    `Object`.`id` = `Rate`.`idObject`
GROUP BY `Object`.id;
```

Is it true that if there is no Rate row with a Rate.idObject equal to Object.id, my object row will not be selected? (So only rows with at least 1 rate will be counted toward results).

If yes is there any way to add a rate AVG value to each Object with a default value to 0 if there is no associated rows with this id in Rate?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: start by using explicit left join instead of implicit comma join.

Comment: *Is it true that if there is no Rate row with a Rate.idObject equal to Object.id, my object row will not be selected?* You use comma-style INNER JOIN (bad practice, use explicit joining clause) which returns rows only when there are matched rows in both tables. So your statement is correct. *If yes is there any way to add a rate AVG value to each Object with a default value to 0 if there is no associated rows with this id in Rate?* LEFT JOIN + COALESCE().

Comment: LEFT JOIN is the keywords I was looking for thank you @P.Salmon, can I ask you to write an answer, so I can flag this post as "solved"?

Comment: LEFT JOIN is the keywords I was looking for thank you @Akina, can I ask you to write an answer, so I can flag this post as "solved"?